# Given two lists V1 and V2 of sizes n and m respectively. Return the list of elements common to both the lists and return the list in sorted order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
class Solution {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> common_element(ArrayList<Integer>v1, ArrayList<Integer>v2) {
        ArrayList<Integer> com = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.sort(v1);
        Collections.sort(v2);
        
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (i < v1.size() && j < v2.size()) {
            if (v1.get(i) == v2.get(j)) {
                com.add(v1.get(i));
                i++;
                j++;
            } else if (v1.get(i) > v2.get(j)) {
                j++;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return com;
    }
}
```

*Question description*:
`Duplicates` may be there in the output list.
What's wrong with my code. When I run it, it will easily and successfully be compiled but when I submit the code, it shows not working like the output coming from my code is wrong.
But where it fails, I'm not able to understand. Can anyone help me to know this....!

Comment: Welcome to the Stacks.  Do you have a debugger available to you?  Are you using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to find `Common elements between given two Lists` is perfectly fine.  Can't figure out why you are not getting the correct verdict.
I'll suggest you to try the below modification and check if it works.

```java
    while (i < v1.size() && j < v2.size())
    {
        int x1 = v1.get(i), x2 = v2.get(j);
        if (x2 == x1)
        {
            com.add(x1);
            i++; j++;
        }
        else if (x1 > x2)
            j++;
        else 
            i++;
    }
```

If the above works then it indicates that there might be some issue with the platform where you are submitting as the approach is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: it is working.....but the difference is in--> **int x1 = v1.get(i), x2 = v2.get(j);** <-- this line only. How and why is it so...!?

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting it online, read the rule most of online competitions required your solution to have main method which read input from file or console and output in certain format. Other than that, your solution looks ok.